# How to find path of current selected project in eclipse plug-in

Tags: eclipse, plugins, path

I am trying to write a eclipse plugin, where I have to find the path of current selected
project. One importent thing is that this is a C or C++ project not a java project that I have to select. I tried some codes-

```
      File currDir = new File(".");
      String path = currDir.getAbsolutePath();
      path = path.substring(0, path.length()-1);
      System.out.println(path);
```

But this one is giving the path of eclipse plugin directory not current project.

```
      IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
      IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();
      IProject[] projects = root.getProjects();
      for (IProject project : projects) {
         try {
            printProjectInfo(project);    
             } catch (CoreException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
             }
        }


       private void printPackageInfos(IJavaProject javaProject)
       throws JavaModelException {
             IPackageFragment[] packages = javaProject.getPackageFragments();
             for (IPackageFragment mypackage : packages) {

                 if (mypackage.getKind() == IPackageFragmentRoot.K_SOURCE) 
                    {                
                      printICompilationUnitInfo(mypackage);
                     }
               }
              }
```

But this one is selecting only java project.

So is there any way to do it .....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```java
public static IProject getCurrentProject(){    
        ISelectionService selectionService =     
            Workbench.getInstance().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService();    

        ISelection selection = selectionService.getSelection();    

        IProject project = null;    
        if(selection instanceof IStructuredSelection) {    
            Object element = ((IStructuredSelection)selection).getFirstElement();    

            if (element instanceof IResource) {    
                project= ((IResource)element).getProject();    
            } else if (element instanceof PackageFragmentRootContainer) {    
                IJavaProject jProject =     
                    ((PackageFragmentRootContainer)element).getJavaProject();    
                project = jProject.getProject();    
            } else if (element instanceof IJavaElement) {    
                IJavaProject jProject= ((IJavaElement)element).getJavaProject();    
                project = jProject.getProject();    
            }    
        }     
        return project;    
    }
```

Hope it works :-)

Comment: Thank you Mr. Sam, for me  PackageFragmentRootContainer was not working , I used PackageFragmentRoot. It is giving me the name of selected project but I was looking for absolute path of that project. Is there any way...